# Why Google Analytics sends two requests when user changes page in Angular?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm using Angular and put next code to index.html

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXX', {'send_page_view': false});
</script>
```

In my app.component I also added this, to track if page changes:

```js
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    (window as any).gtag('event', 'page_view', { path: event.urlAfterRedirects });
  }
});
```

I debbugged the code in Visual Studio and everything seems to be working ok. Data is received and displayed in Google Analytics Realtime section, but I'm curious is this ok for SPA applications to send 'page_view' event or should I always send 'config' event when user navigates to new page?

Another thing is, 2 requests are made to Google Analytics. The first one just after user navigates and the second a couple of seconds later:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to always send pageviews on navigations on an SPA. You typically send configuration only on real page loads or when you want to change the standard set of fields (event parameters) to be included with every subsequent event.

Regarding your double call issue. It may or may not be okay. Check each call. Check the `en` parameter value. It stands for the event name. One of them has to be `page_view`. The other can be an auto event or another `page_view`. If it's the latter, then it looks like your NavigationEnd is being triggered twice. Or maybe you're sending the additional pageview from somewhere else. It's not ideal to have double pageviews. Probably won't hurt too much in your case, but it is still wrong enough to fix.

Comment: After disabling: Google Analytics 4 admin > Data Streams -> Enhanced Measurement -> “Show advanced settings” in the “Page views” section and disabled “Page changes based on browser history events”, I now only have one event if I navigate to another site - https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/duplicate-events-in-google-analytics-4-and-how-to-fix-them/.


But I noticed that now { path: event.urlAfterRedirects } is not sent to the GA api.

Comment: you aren't really interested in "path" as it stands. Check the values of `dp` and `dl` in the call. They should indicate the new url. They stand for document path and document location. The location should be href, basically, while path is just path.

Comment: I created new property page and the additional data is now sent by the client and visible in analytics, there was probably something wrong with existing. I found documentation regarding this behaviour:
Whenever someone loads a page of your website or their browser history state is changed by the active site, an enhanced measurement event called page_view is sent from your website to Google Analytics. Since the event is sent automatically, you don't need to send pageview data to Analytics manually.

You can't send additional data in config event, therefore I sent it manually.